# Dependend end-date formula for my Ganttchart-template

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gantt-chart

i wasnt sure which title i should use so i better explain...

I try to create a Ganttchart template, there are already some out there but they dont have tasks which are dependend on other tasks end-dates. so heres my link to my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vson1A2-ns7tLiJXbDgJdxUStBs0YYeHANhFlafHapU/edit?usp=sharing

so basically i have a list of tasks, each task has its own id in column A. the first task has a fixed start date (start date of project), all others should be using the end dates of other dependend tasks. Im linking them by putting the task-ID in column E, if there are more tasks to be dependend on i use a "," to separate and i expect the formula to choose the latest date of all dependend end-dates

i tried already hours with chatgpt to find a solution but none works, i tried to use only some cells as reference to the formula might not apply to the full sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(SPLIT(E3, ","), A:A)), VLOOKUP(SPLIT(E3, ","), A:D, 3, FALSE), "")))
```

and

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E5, ",", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"), A:A, 0)), VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E5, ",", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"), A:D, 4, FALSE), 0))
```

anyone has some suggestions? i appreciate!

Comment: Your end goal is not clear. I suggest that you manually enter a representative sample of what the results should look like for the first 5 to 10 tasks.

Comment: oh ok. i just edited the sheet. i hope i dont have a logic error in my goal of the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this formula:**

```
=MAX(QUERY(FILTER({$A$2:$B2\$D$2:$D2};MATCH($A$2:$A2;TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(E3;","));0));"Select Col3"))
```

*Note: You can't use Arrayformula because it won't work with Query.*

Here's the result:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en#)

Comment: Should you have further question, feel free to let me know.

Comment: it works as expected! thank you so much!!

Comment: not sure if i can just ask you here directly or i open a new thread. Do you know how i have to adjust your great formula to ignore weekends? right know it just uses day by day